# Google Fit api does not track data

Tags: android, android-sensors, google-fit, android-10.0

Google fit works fine on devices lower than android 10 . However on some devices running on android 10 does not track data .All permissions are included (it works on my Pixel running on android 10). Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please add all the relevant code of your project here.

Answer (score 0):

For all apps running on Android 10 your app must request the following Android permissions to access physical activity data using the fitness APIs in addition to the scopes described above.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
```

It's runtime permission that you need to ask in your Activity.

More info: https://developers.google.com/fit/android/authorization#android_permissions

Comment: Yeah this permission is included . The problem is that on some devices running on android 10 does not work.

Comment: @Georgeous - Are you asking runtime permission for Android 10?

Comment: All permissions are grated. It works on Pixel 3a (running on Android 10)